# NoClassDefFoundError occurs when using the swagger2Markup

Tags: java

**swagger2Markup maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger2markup</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**test method**
When I run this method, it goes wrong

```
    @Test
    public void generateAsciiDocs() throws Exception {
        //    输出Ascii格式
        Swagger2MarkupConfig config = new Swagger2MarkupConfigBuilder()
                .withMarkupLanguage(MarkupLanguage.ASCIIDOC)
                .withOutputLanguage(Language.ZH)
                .withPathsGroupedBy(GroupBy.TAGS)
                .withGeneratedExamples()
                .withoutInlineSchema()
                .build();

        Swagger2MarkupConverter.from(new URL("http://localhost:8088/v2/api-docs?group=api"))
                .withConfig(config)
                .build()
                .toFolder(Paths.get("src/docs/asciidoc/generated/all"));
    }
```

**run later**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector
```

## what the NoClassDefFoundError ???

Comment: [what is NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java). BeanIntrospector class is available in `commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar`, add [commons-beanutils](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4) dependency in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because maven Rely on the conflict